# Setting time passed since last message sent / recieved

Tags: jquery

**My Chat Script So Far:**

```
initChat: function () {

    var cont = $('#chats');
    var list = $('.chats', cont);
    var form = $('.chat-form', cont);
    var input = $('input', form);
    var btn = $('.btn', form);
    
    $('.scroller', cont).slimScroll({
        scrollTo: list.height()
    });

    var handleClick = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var text = input.val();
        if (text.length == 0) {
            return;
        }
        
        var contains = text.match(/(@Tim marshall:|@Mark Smyth:)/i) === null ? "left" : "right";
            sender;
        
        if(contains === 'right'){
            var sender = 'Private message from: <a href="#" class="name">Bob Nilson</a>&nbsp;<br />';
        }else{
            var sender = '<a href="#" class="name">Bob Nilson</a>&nbsp;';
        };

        var time = new Date();
        var time_str = time.toString('MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss');
        var tpl = '';
        tpl += '<li class="' + contains + '">';
        tpl += '<img class="avatar" alt="" src="../../assets/admin/layout/img/avatar1.jpg"/>';
        tpl += '<div class="message">';
        tpl += '<span class="arrow"></span>';
        tpl += sender;
        tpl += '<span class="datetime">at ' + time_str + '</span>';
        tpl += '<span class="body">';
        tpl += text.toString().replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;").replace(/'/g, "&#39;").replace(/"/g, "&#34;");
        tpl += '</span>';
        tpl += '</div>';
        tpl += '</li>';

        var msg = list.append(tpl);
        input.val("");
        $('.scroller', cont).slimScroll({
            scrollTo: list.height()
        });
    }

    /*
    $('.scroller', cont).slimScroll({
        scrollTo: list.height()
    });
    */

    $('body').on('click', '.message .name', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent click event

        var name = $(this).text(); // get clicked user's full name
        input.val('@' + name + ':'); // set it into the input field
        Metronic.scrollTo(input); // scroll to input if needed
    });

    btn.click(handleClick);
    input.keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            handleClick();
            return false; //<---- Add this line
        }
    });
},
```

This script section starts on line 484 in [index.js](http://rafflebananza.com/assets/admin/pages/scripts/index.js). You can play around with my staff chat [here](http://rafflebananza.com/admin/index.html).

Upon sending a message, you see something like this:

> Bob Nilson at Fri Jun 27 2014 21:30:45 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
>
> Test Message

What I am looking to do is to display a dynamic time since the message was sent. In my understanding, I believe in theory I need to edit:

```
var time = new Date();
var time_str = time.toString('MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss');
```

to be a timestamp and then run through all my .datetime classes somehow displaying a time since. Alike Facebook, I would like to have certain times from lets say from 10800 (3 hours in seconds) to 14400 (4 hours in seconds) to say 'About four hours ago'.

How can I achieve something like this?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to be able to redraw it easily. If you're repainting the label every frame / cycle, then you're fine.

So you can store a timestamp for each comment posted, or you can store a global variable with the time of the last posted comment.

Then, since you know the current time, you can find the time since the last comment and then use an if/then statement for each of your cases:

```
timeDiff = currentTime - lastTimeStamp;
label = "";

if (timeDiff < 600){
   label = "A moment ago"
}
else if (timeDiff < 1200){
   label = "1 minute ago"
}
//and so on
```

Then use the `label` variable to display the message you want

Alternatively, you can create a map or parallel arrays to map a `timeDiff` to a `label`, then loop over each one until you get a match.

EDIT: To get the `lastTimeStamp` variable, you can either store it globally and update it each time a post is made, or you can loop through each of your data points each frame/ cycle to get it dynamically every time. The global variable idea is advantageous in that it doesn't take as much processing power. The loop idea is advantageous in that it doesn't require you to update a global variable everytime a post is made.

So, to do the loop idea: Assuming you have an array of posts called something like `posts`, filled with objects of type `Post` or something, and each `Post` object has a `timeStamp` variable, you can loop through it like so:

```
var lastTimeStamp = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++){
   if (posts[i].timeStamp > lastTimeStamp){
      lastTimeStamp = posts[i].timeStamp;
   }
}
```

And so, that's how you can get the `lastTimeStamp` variable. Of course, it'll look a little different in your code depending on your variable names and/or implementation of `Posts`

Comment: +1 Thank you for your input :) How do I do a constant loop through them all finding their timestamps and then dynamically changing them please?